# Getting the index of a list of user generated controls upon clicking

Tags: c#, winforms, list, button, controls

I am working on an app that decodes messages coming over a serial port and puts out user buttons based on that. I store these in a List called "buttons". Now, in order to demonstrate two way communications I want to send out a message based on the "color" property that I defined in the user control. So if I click on a red button the program send out an "r", and so on. I would like to know how to get the list index of the clicked button, or even just the property of the given button.

So for example, based on the message coming in from the serial port my program adds a button to the list. I then set it's various parameters like location, size, color, etc. When I click it, based on what color it is I want to send a corresponding character through the serial port.

I have defined a button click event handler for this. I plan on getting the list index of the button in the event handler, I just don't know how. I tried using the sender of the event, I tried just using "this", I looked all over but I haven't the slightest idea of how to do this.

This is where I add my buttons:

```
guiButton newButton = new guiButton();
EventHandler myHandler = new EventHandler(guibutton_click);
newButton.Click += myHandler;
newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
newButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 10);
buttons.Add(newButton);
this.Controls.Add(newButton);
```

And this would be the event

```
private void guibutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //somehow get ID number here (which is an int)
        if (buttons[ID].color == "green") port.WriteLine("g");
        if (buttons[ID].color == "blue") port.WriteLine("b");
        if (buttons[ID].color == "red") port.WriteLine("r");
        if (buttons[ID].color == "yellow") port.WriteLine("y");
    }
```

And just for reference, this is my list of buttons:

```
List<guiButton> buttons = new List<guiButton>();
```

Edit: I managed to get the user button's color property from the event handler's sender object, but I still need the list index of the button because I would like to delete the button and remove it from the list upon a double click. Would this be possible? Does the sender information contain this as well?

Comment: Have you checked the sender parameter in the event handler? It should contain the "sending" button that you clicked on.

Comment: as cbale said, cast sender to Button and then work with it. Like this: `var btn = sender as Button; if (btn.Text == "green")...`

Comment: Thanks, Nino's solution worked for getting the color parameter (with the slight change that it needs to be a "guiButton" not as just a "Button") but I still would like to know how to get the list index of the clicked button if at all possible, because upon a double click event I'd like for it to delete it.